# Workaround for JavaFX Application on older versions of java

Tags: java, javafx

I developed an app that uses JavaFX for the GUI. The main issue I am having is that the people that will be using the app don't have the latest version of java and some can't upgrade their JRE because they have other applications that have a dependency on a specific java version. So my question is, what type of workaround can be done on the code to make sure the application will run regardless of the jre version? Is it possible to extract the JavaFX library and add it to the buildpath? Perhaps a solution to my problem is not possible but want to get someone's input on how to come up with a possible workaround.

The application works fine for me under java version 1.8.0_05

Thanks in advance

Comment: Consider using a [self-contained native package](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) which embeds the JRE into the package itself, rather than relying on the JRE installed on the client machine.

Comment: @James_D I was looking into that. That might be a possible solution.

Comment: @James_D Do you know of a tutorial for that but for Eclipse?

Comment: I've always just used the command line version, to be honest. But if you are using [e(fx)clipse](http://www.eclipse.org/efxclipse/index.html) (which I recommend), there's a [brief tutorial](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Efxclipse/Tutorials/Tutorial1) which includes deployment.

Comment: @James_D The main downfall to doing this is that my application now increased in size by a lot. It used to be 1.50MB and now its over 140MB (because of the embedded JRE). Is there an alternate solution?